# asp.net issue with datasrc and datafld to get XML info

Tags: html, asp.net, xml

Using IE, I have a working example code that able show my profile information on XML site included userid, name, company, phone number and etc.

I added HTML codes,

```
<xml id="XmlUserInfo" src="http://usmdlcdoww002.intranet.dow.com/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=me"> </xml>
    </div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Number:&nbsp;
    </br>
    <input datasrc="XmlUserInfo" datafld="cn" type="text" name="Name" size="30" />
```

XmlUserInfo display a list of information about me. Now I want my name to show up in textbox or whatever in `<input>` . After I run it, the input box is empty which nothing there. Am I doing it wrong?

Here is XML example display,

```
<MyData>
  <user>
  <uid>U580784</uid> 
  <cn>Frank, Bradley (B)</cn> 
  <sn>Frank</sn> 
  <givenName>Bradley</givenName> 
  <initials>B</initials> 
  </user>
</MyData>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It required to add table to make this work like this,

```
<xml id="XmlUserInfo" src="http://usmdlcdoww002.intranet.dow.com/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=me"> </xml>
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ID:&nbsp;
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Number:&nbsp;
    <table datasrc="#XmlUserInfo" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <input datafld="cn" type="text" name="Name" size="30">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```